# I have two different types of quotes show up when using Terminal on a Mac with Autodesk Maya

Tags: macos, terminal

I am using Terminal to execute commands for rendering purposes with Autodesk Maya, and have constantly run into an issue of being able to have two different kinds of double quotations (left of <kbd>return</kbd> key).

One appears to be italicized somehow. I have found the non-italicized double quotation allows the command to run properly, but I have to constantly copy and paste it from a previous `*.sh`.

I can’t type it directly. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have enabled "Smart Quotes" but in my testing of `Terminal.app` on Yosemite it doesn't affect the quotes. Just in case check your Keyboard System Preference pane… maybe you have a substitution enabled from an older version of OS X (the columns to the left of the Smart Quotes preference see below).

[image: Smart Quotes Preference]

You could also check for something else doing autocorrection to convert quotes into Smart Quotes (e.g. TextExpander, Keyboard Maestro, LaunchBar)

Comment: Thank you cppl - that was the trick, but not sure why...